# Error with align in quill-image-resize-vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem with alignment in the images when I use "quill-image-resize-vue", align to the center or right, but when I go to see the result, It is left aligned.

It doesn't happen in all cases, but I haven't been able to identify in which cases it fails.

The only thing I've noticed is that when it works, the img property has "display: block" and "margin: auto".

This is my code:

```
import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor";
import { ImageDrop } from "quill-image-drop-module";
import ImageResize from "quill-image-resize-vue";

export default {
  name: "format-document-form",
  components: {
    VueEditor,
  },
  data: function () {
      editorData: "<p>Desarrollo de la agenda...</p>",
      customModulesForEditor: [
        { alias: "imageDrop", module: ImageDrop },
        { alias: "imageResize", module: ImageResize },
      ],
      editorSettings: {
        modules: {
          imageDrop: true,
          imageResize: {},
        },
      },
   }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<vue-editor
  v-model="editorData"
  :customModules="customModulesForEditor"
  :editorOptions="editorSettings"
></vue-editor>
```

When I'm creating it looks like this:
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruQUX.png)

But when I interpret the HTML, it looks like this:
[result html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r6DG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I recently added quill-image-resize-vue to my vue2 editor and found that the following set of steps in the editor preserve the alignment:

1. Click the Alignment you need.
2. Resize the image.
3. Save the html data.

Just resizing the image works fine but image alignment as a standalone action does not seem to work.

The alignment options available in the main Vue Editor toolbar seemed to align the images correctly so I'm just using those. To disable alignment within the image resize, I used:

```
editorSettings: {
                modules: {
                  imageResize: {
                    modules: ['Resize', 'DisplaySize']
                  },
                }
              }
```